# Is there a relation between available RAM and Ring size in OpenStack SWIFT?

Tags: ram, openstack, ring, openstack-swift

I was reading about OpenStack SWIFT and its different components. But I have a doubt, if available RAM is more, then can we afford to have Rings of bigger size ? And how does Ring Size affect the system ?

Answer (score 0):

**Ring size has nothing to do with the RAM size**.

Following is the command to build the object Ring:

```
swift-ring-builder <builder_file> create <part_power> <replicas> <min_part_hours>
```

I am quoting the explanation text for above command  from the documentation about [ring-preparation](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/swift/deployment_guide.html#ring-preparing).

**This will start the ring build process creating the  with 2^ partitions.  is the time in hours before a specific partition can be moved in succession (24 is a good value for this).**

It means if you choose  to be 10 then **2^10=1024** partitions are going to be created.

You can read in detail from the [SWIFT Administrator’s Guide](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/swift/admin_guide.html?highlight=rings).